# Set Rows inVisible JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, row, invisible

I have a requirement to show only specific rows in the JTable upon filter.

I cannot change the model of the JTable, since changing that will also change my rowIndex. So only way to maintain the index and show specific rows is to make some rows invisible.

How can I make table rows invisible in JTable.

I want to retain the index after filtering the rows. For Example If the table has 4 rows (A,B,C,D). The selectedIndex of D will be 3 in this case.... After Filtering B now the Table will Contain (A,C,D). Now selecting D will return selectedIndex 2. In my case I want to retain the selected for D as 3

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

`JTable` has support for row sorting and filtering built in.

Take a look at [How to use tables, Sorting and Filtering](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting)

This will allow you to maintain the table model and filter the view, so only the view changes...

Comment: I know about that.. I want to retain the index after filtering the rows. For Example If the table has 4 rows (A,B,C,D). The selectedIndex of D will be 3 in this case.... After Filtering B now the Table will Contain (A,C,D). Now selecting D will return selectedIndex 2. In my case I want to retain the selected for D as 3

Comment: @SurendranD: `JTable` has methods to covert between model and view indices.

Comment: @SurendranD Read the tutorials. You can convert between the view and model indexes very easily